# I am not able to ask questions on Ask Ubuntu

Tags: support, asking-questions, closed-questions, post-ban

I am a new ask ubuntu user and recently I just asked **only 1 question** on it about my computer being stuck. I was flagged for duplicate / off-topic questions. My question was deleted.

**It was actually on topic** but if it was even off-topic then I also should get another chance to ask a good question. whenever I go to ask questions I get the prompt that I can only ask 1 question per 1 week. That's is unfair.

I have given really good answers by then (at least I can answer and help the community). That is why I have **108 reputation**(not counting the association bonus). So that can be a reason to give me the privilege to ask questions. If you won't believe that I have only asked 1 question then moderators can check it.

Edit:The error I am getting -

[image: this is the message]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing we can do - the limit is automatically imposed by the system and can't be lifted by mods.

By the way, you can ask 1 question per week, apparently.

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/322419) which describes the thought behind this particular question limit.

I'm a bit surprised that this happened after asking only one question*, but the only thing you can do about it is to try to make sure your next questions are good. You chose to delete your question - deleting makes things worse, not better, with regard to bans and limits. Your question could probably have been closed as a duplicate instead and in that case I doubt that you would have run into the limit.

* note that these limits and bans are meant to be against the user rather than the account, so it's possible that activity from another account or someone else sharing your IP address could affect them

Comment: Ok fine @Zanna thanks for giving you precious time

Comment: :) no worries, I'm happy to help

Comment: @Zanna *"deleting makes things worse"*.  That's good info, and something I didn't realize even with some 8k rep across 4 Stack sites.  Any idea on why that is?  Is this documented somewhere that "mere mortals" :-) can see?  I would honestly have thought that deleting a poorly received question was the right thing to do.  I thought there was (is?) even a badge for it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds The actual rules behind the question ban are secret, nobody really knows how it works by design, so there is no documentation. There is an FAQ but it is vague on details and mostly focuses on ending a ban. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: Does SE even know the rules :)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yeah I would have thought so too! Mark Kirby linked to the only documentation I know about on this

Comment: @JacobVlijm maybe our glorious overlord Community♦ knows them

Comment: @Zanna Can I still ask my ubuntu related questions on unix and linux without fear ? Is their some other community for ubuntu users ? Will i get banned from linux and unix also  ? Is their some  other community to ask ubuntu realated questions other than stack overflow ?

Comment: @AkshajSingla you can ask Ubuntu questions on Unix & Linux, but do try to make sure they are well received by researching first, looking for similar questions, reading the guidelines in the Help Center, etc. There are many Linux and Ubuntu communities around. [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) is a nice place.

Comment: @AkshajSingla :) good to know :)

Comment: @Zanna Because of my good answers I am no longer banned from asking questions :) thank you for your guidance. :) :):)

Comment: @AkshajSingla excellent! good job :)

Comment: Why can't I ping you @Zanna? Are you getting my pings? It does not show on the top bar, I mean I cannot auto-complete the ping.

Comment: it's because this is my post so I automatically get notified @someone

Comment: @Zanna On every post.

Comment: you can't ping people on posts they have not interacted with @someone